# Removing ImageOverlay in map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have big problems with replacing an image in a if sentence. I remove the image first. But I cant place a new image when inside an if-sentence.

```
var image= 'garage.png'; 
 var imageUrl = image,
 imageBounds = L.latLngBounds([
        [63.431004174, 10.397958755],
        [63.430433118, 10.399938226]])
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio').fitBounds(imageBounds);
var overlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
map.removeLayer(overlay);



 // this is the if  that appears later in the code //



 function changeImages(newValue){
  var slider = newValue; 



if(slider < 5){

    var image = 'garageAltered.png';
    var imageUrl = image,imageBounds = L.latLngBounds([
        [63.431004174, 10.397958755],
        [63.430433118, 10.399938226]])
   var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'examples.map-i86nkdio')
    .fitBounds(imageBounds);
    var overlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

}



  }
```

Comment: What mapping API is this? MapBox?

Comment: As far as I can tell map.removeLayer should work. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/leaflet-js/eGG7MOufCjo/fIsp511JD78J) for an example.

Comment: For some reason this wont work when I have i inside an if sentence. Without the if- sentence it works fine. The problem is that I need he if to get my code to work...

Comment: Could you alter your question to include the code related to using the `if` statement?

Comment: I have tried som other stuff in the if-sentence and the if is working, just not the image part.

Comment: Okay, so what's not working? Your `removeLayer` statement is outside the `if` statement. An `addTo` statement is inside the `if` statement. Is the problem that the overlay is not being added or that it is not being removed?

Comment: the problem is that I cant add a new overlay Thats the main goal.If I can replace the Overlay with a new one inside the if, Im happy.The if statement is actually inside an function, so maybe thats the problem..